# how to serialize associative array with javascript save it in cookie and then read it with php?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

first of all i know that there are many questions similar to mine. Of course i have read them all, but i couldn't find the solution or understand how to solve my problem. 
here is the main problem: i have an associative array in java script which i want to serialize it and save it in a cookie, then i want to read this cookie with php by using unserialize method. so i can't find a proper way to serialize the associative array.

**there is javascript**

```
function renewCookie(){
    var myArray = {radius: radius, type:type, date:price, name:company}
    serializeValue = JSON.stringify(myArray);/* i used this serialize function that i found on web http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/ but it didn't work.*/
    createCookie('parameters',serializeValue ,999);   
  }
  function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
```

**there is php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE["parameters"])){
            $UserParam = json_decode($_COOKIE["parameters"]);/*I unserialize the cookie because i suppose that it is serialized*/
            echo"<script>function readCookie(){ getLocationFunction(".$UserParam["radius"].",\"".$UserParam["type"]."\",\"".$UserParam["date"]."\",\"".$UserParam["name"]."\")}</script>";
    }
    else{setcookie("parameters","$defaultParam",time()+3600);}
?>
```

dose someone know how to read the cookie created by javascript with php? I also explain that i have an associative array because i want to have both multyvalue cookie and the name of the keys.  pleas for helping me provide some code. if you want more explanation pleas ask. Thank you in advance!!

**update**: the code above it works fine with your suggestions, but it works only on firefox and chrome, not in opera, safari and explorer. dose anybody see what i am doing wrong??

Comment: How about using JSON instead of serialize?

Comment: Specify "it didn't work". In which way does the serialized representation of the javascript object differ from from the one that PHP expects?

Comment: Just being pedantic: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. You're working with an object literal. Arrays themselves are, in fact, also objects. Historically the first implementation of JS didn't have arrays, only objects... just a bit of history for you

Comment: @oswald when i serialized the object (not array as Elias said) on javascript i couldn't unserialized it on php. it gives me back an error. but the solution of mike brand worked, but only on firefox and chrome not on opera,safari and explorer. any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use JSON serialization.

in javascript:

```
serializeValue = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

in PHP

```
$UserParam = json_decode($_COOKIE["parameters"]);
```

Note that `$UserParam` would be on object in this case. If you want to force an associative array use:

```
$UserParam = json_decode($_COOKIE["parameters"], true);
```

Comment: When working with JS, forget about other data-interchange formats and take advantage of the native JSON API whenever you can.

Comment: @mike brand: first of all thank you for your replay, but i have 2 questions. 1) do i have to input any library to use JSON.stringify function or not. 2) on php side is there something like json_encode() by that I mean if there is the opposite of json_decode()?

Comment: @gerti In PHP there is both json_decode and json_encode.  The javascript JSON library is natively supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: @gerti did you search for it on php.net?

Comment: guys i tried it and it work fine on firefox and chrome, but it didn't work on opera, safari and explorer. Do you know something? because i read that they support it but it doesn't run on my machine! plz help!!!!

Comment: @MikeBrant your solution with JSON.stringify and json_decode doesn't work on opera, safari and explorer, but only on firefox an chrome. above i have updated the code plz see if i am doing something wrong!

Comment: @gerti I don't know what browser versions you are using, but the compatibility in IE goes back to 8.0, in Opera to 10.5, and Safari to 4.0. For more compatibility see this:  http://caniuse.com/json  Have you looked at console to see if you have any errors?